# Using HtmlUnit, I have a HtmlTableRow, how can I get all its content as a string value?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit.

I have an object of HtmlTableRow type, and I want to dump all of the content to a variable, how can I do this?

i.e. just want to get the HTML like:  `<tr><td>....</td></tr>`

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the HtmlTableRow javadoc page](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html?com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlTableRow.html); I will tell you that the answer is on that page.  I hate to get all tough-love on you, but this is your sixth HtmlUnit question in 48 hours, and many of them have been completely answerable by just looking at the HtmlUnit javadocs.  I'm not sure you're ever looking there first before coming here, and that's just not respectful of this community.

Comment: actually I did look, I guess I am just not seeing it.

Comment: I guess not.  Another hint -- the method you need has been in one of the answers of another of your very own HtmlUnit questions.